# Cloud Function + Cloud Build: How to add a file to function at build time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I have a scenario where I've got a secrets json file in a storage bucket that I would like to `cp` into the cloud function's dir at build time in Cloud Build.

The `cp` command works, but the file is neither in the zip that gets deployed or in the code at runtime as the function errors out when called due to missing config values.

Here's the `cloudbuild.yaml`

```
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil"
    args: ["cp", "gs://GCP-PROJECT/production.json", "./config/production.json"]
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil"
    args: ["cp", "gs://GCP-PROJECT/default.json", "./config/default.json"]
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    args:
      - beta
      - functions
      - deploy
      - --region=europe-west1
      - --memory=128
      - --runtime=nodejs8
      - --trigger-topic=mailsend-sg
      - --stage-bucket=gen-function1-stage
      - --timeout=20s
      - --source=.
      - --entry-point=sendMail
      - send-sendgrid
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    args:
      - beta
      - functions
      - deploy
      - --region=europe-west1
      - --memory=128
      - --runtime=nodejs8
      - --trigger-http
      - --stage-bucket=gen-function2-stage
      - --timeout=20s
      - --source=.
      - --entry-point=makeMail
      - make-fs-mail
timeout: "1600s"
```

Am I doing something wrong with the localfile path?

Thanks stackoverflow :)

Comment: Could you post the error log here? That will help with troubleshooting it. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried resolving this issue using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56568998/9738014)?

Answer (score 2):

In your build steps 'args' you put the production.json and default.json in /config folder.

So you need to specify `- --source=./config` in your build steps instead of `- --source=.` like so:

```
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil"
    args: ["cp", "gs://GCP-PROJECT/production.json", "./config/production.json"]
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil"
    args: ["cp", "gs://GCP-PROJECT/default.json", "./config/default.json"]
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    args:
      - beta
      - functions
      - deploy
      - --region=europe-west1
      - --memory=128
      - --runtime=nodejs8
      - --trigger-topic=mailsend-sg
      - --stage-bucket=gen-function1-stage
      - --timeout=20s
      - --source=./config
      - --entry-point=sendMail
      - send-sendgrid
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    args:
      - beta
      - functions
      - deploy
      - --region=europe-west1
      - --memory=128
      - --runtime=nodejs8
      - --trigger-http
      - --stage-bucket=gen-function2-stage
      - --timeout=20s
      - --source=./config
      - --entry-point=makeMail
      - make-fs-mail
timeout: "1600s"
```

That should resolve the Cloud Functions deployment issue. If you still run into errors, post the error/debugging log here